# How to create nested dictionary in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I try to append or add values to an already created nested Dictionary.
This is the dictionary:

```
set ldifValues {
    00001 {
        first abc
        second 4ee
        third 000
        nested {111-11111 111-11112}
        person 5034
    }
```

I try to create a new one with:

```
dict with ldifValues 00002 {
    lappend first abc
    lappend second 5ee
    lappend third 0101
    lappend nested 0100-5020 0100-5033 0101-50335
    lappend personnel 5033
}
```

I would like to add a new key started `00002` with all other values. Especially I couldn't create `00002` key as new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set things nested key by nested key:

```
dict set ldifValues 00002 first abc
dict set ldifValues 00002 second 5ee
dict set ldifValues 00002 third 0101
dict set ldifValues 00002 nested {0100-5020 0100-5033 0101-50335}
dict set ldifValues 00002 personnel 5033
```

Or you can do a bulk set by using a dictionary as the value to set:

```
dict set ldifValues 00002 {
    first abc
    second 5ee
    third 0101
    nested {0100-5020 0100-5033 0101-50335}
    personnel 5033
}
```

`dict with` is more suitable for updating an existing nested dictionary structure.

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like I missed use of "dict with"

Answer (score 0):

I would create a complex [`dict`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm) the following way:

```
set ldifValues [dict create]
dict set ldifValues 00001 {
    first abc
    second 4ee
    third 000
    nested {111-11111 111-11112}
    person 5034
}
dict set ldifValues 00002 {
    first abc
    second 5ee
    third 0101
    nested {0100-5020 0100-5033 0101-50335}
    personnel 5033
}

dict get $ldifValues 00002 personnel
# => 5033
```

`dict set` basically adds a new dict entry if the key doesn't already exists. If it exists, it will overwrite the existing key/value pair. So you can perfectly use `dict set` to add to an existing dict.